# Can't use cancelAnimationFrame. Nothing happens (chrome)

Tags: javascript

**Problem:** I can't cancel requestAnimationFrame using by chromes recognized cancelAnimationFrame.

**What I tried:** I used console.log but no errors displayed. I console.logged the cancelAnimationFrame and I get undefined, while the request counterpart logs fine. I also tried different version of cancelAnimationFrame, including the prefixed versions:

```
cancelAnimationFrame
webkitCancelAnimationFrame
window.cancelAnimationFrame etc..
```

I also tried putting the canceling code into the function but as expected that doesn't really matter.

**Question:** Why can't I stop my requestAnimationFrame? Is canceling it my way even recommended?

---

http://jsfiddle.net/p8hv15j4/2/

---

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var currentPos = 0;

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

function fn() {
    currentPos += 5;

    elem.style.left = currentPos + "px";

    if (Math.abs(currentPos) >= 900) {
        currentPos = -500;
    }
        requestAnimationFrame(fn);
}
fn();

setTimeout(function() {
     cancelAnimationFrame(fn);
   }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` returns an ID, which is what you need to pass to `cancelAnimationFrame`.

In fact, it works exactly the same way as `set/clearTimeout` - setting it returns an identifier, and you cancel the identifier.